# Rails Deleting a Model that has Many Relationships Without Tanking the Server that is Maintainable

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, maintainability

I'm using Rails 3.2

I have an issue I'm trying to wrap my head around. I have a model which is kind of at the top of a pyramid of many other models which belong to it, and there are more models that belong to those other models. So just calling topmodel.destroy is obviously very slow (relying on :dependent => destroy to get rid of the related models)

I've found :dependent => delete which sounds close to the solution, but there are a lot of times when I do want to use :dependent => destroy (for instance, when removing just one of my middle level models and making sure some callbacks get obeyed when destroying bottem level models.

Is there a good, maintainable way to delete like this sometimes, but destroy the rest of the time?

I know I can make a huge nasty pile of code that calls delete manually on each related model, but I'm working with a large number of models and new ones are needed frequently, so I don't want to do it this way. I did some googling and searched Stack Exchange, but I couldn't find what I wanted (many I don't know the proper term for this kind of action).

Comment: you could just softdelete.

Comment: I hadn't heard of softdelete before. It looks like you just move the record to a delete table (so I would need a matching table for every table I have? Or a boolean column to mark them as soft deleted)? I don't need to recover the record though. Can you elaborate how it applies to my situation?

Comment: Is the delete being triggered by a user action? If so, you can use a background job to do the delete.

Comment: My trouble is that even if I run it as a background task, I run into memory problems because rails is loading so many active record objects (in order to obey callbacks). I should have mentioned that, it's what I meant by Tanking the Server; Yes it is a user action.

Comment: I guess soft delete allows me to just set the topmodel to not show, which is something I can think about. So thank you for your suggestion. I am just not sure I want to give users the impression they've deleted data when they haven't, nor am I sure I want to have 10000 more or less abandoned records sitting in my database. I will have to ponder it.